# How to add latest goole play service android application in older version phone?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I integrate firebase in my android application. Firebase will support the google play service from 9.0.0 version . I used google play service for map in the application. When i install the app in the phones that have the lower version of 9.0.0 play service,The app won't run unless update the google play service

These are the codes that i added for fire base . And i added a json file that get during firebase integration.

```
packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) can help you with your problem. This link will serve you as a guide on how to set up properly the Google Play Services.

1. Open the `build.gradle` file inside your application module directory.
2. Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services. For example:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   ...

   dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
   }
   ```

There is a list of Google Play services API and their corresponding description in build.gradle in the link above for you to follow.

3. Save the changes and click Sync Project with Gradle Files in the toolbar.

Then, that's it, you can now begin developing features with the Google Play services APIs.